# What is correct programming flow for a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on my first Rails app and I'm enjoying it so far. I am building my website on Bootstrap with SCSS. So until now, I didn't get to write any Ruby code, I've been just working on my views and generated 2 controllers until now.

I came at a situation where a controller should  have more than one view. This is a products page... One action (ie. "show" action) should list all products, but when there is an ID present in the URL (ie. mysite.com/products/1) I want a different view to appear with the particular information of that view.

Well of course, I have no models or database data until now, no migrations no nothing, I am simply working on the design and later I'll work on the logic. However, I want to be able to differentiate views on mysite.com/products and mysite/products/N so I can work on my HTML/SCSS at least.

How can I achieve this? And how do I continue with my project's logic after I've set everything with the views?

Comment: Your approach doesn't make much sense, use plain html if you just want a mockup.

Comment: Well it will be a full Rails application in the near future, so I wanted to start it that way... What are my solutions?

Comment: I don't want to be mean here, but your solution would be to start learning some RoR...

Comment: A side note - the correct flow on a Rails app is: define your entities/models, add the logic in controllers and, *lastly*, style your views. Starting with the views is a far off approach.

Comment: Alright, thanks. You're not being mean, but helpful. So I guess I'll just save what I've done until now (HTML & SCSS), delete those controllers and start with the logic instead, right?

Comment: Traditionally, every controller action has its own view. In your case, index and show, both of which show up if you generate your starting point using the scaffolding.

Comment: Rails is not meant to be used that way... but it is possible to create a database-free model that will always be populated with some junk and therefore be displayable. Mimicking a database-backed model without a database is not too hard (especially with Rails 4' `ActiveModel::Model`), but is it reasonable when it's just as easy to create a DB-backed one? Well if you seriously want to know, I can write up a story, sure...

Answer (score -1):

At the command line:

```
$ rails new product_demo
$ cd product_demo
$ rails g controller Products
$ rails g model Product
```

Edit `config/routes`:

```
resources :products
```

Command line enter:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Edit `app/controllers/products_controller.rb:

```
def index
end

def show
end
```

Create `app/views/products/index.html.erb`:

```
Index page (put HTML here)
```

Create `app/views/products/show.html.erb`:

```
Detail page (put HTML here)
```

View the products index at:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/
```

View the product detail page (`show` view/action) at:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/1
```

No data yet, but that's okay and you can work on the general design. However if you want to work on the layout of the (eventual) data, you may want to start with a scaffold instead, the benefit of which is you can immediately begin entering data:

```
rails g scaffold Products name:string
```

The drawback of this approach is you'll have more stuff to remove to accomplish your design objectives, but you'll have a working app and can enter test data directly into the (generated) UI.

Now you can work on styling both pages, from your example: mysite.com/products (`app/views/products/index.html.erb`) and mysite.com/products/N (`app/views/products/show.html.erb`).